# How can I search through all mail folders on my iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios, email, gmail

My Gmail account has multiple folders and labels. The iPad mail app can search through one of the folders. How can I search through all of it at once?

Answer (score 1):

You can search through the All Mail folder instead.

Comment: Yes, but I purposefully don't sync that to conserve disk space. Is there a way in the app to search all the folders rather than just selecting the folder which has "all mail" in it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so.

Answer (score -1):

No way to do so on apple mail that I've seen, I've resorted to the cueup.com app (formerly called greplin) which has a search functionality that indexes all accounts you link to it, or cloudmagic as an alternative. it will pull up emails via search and open up the message on the browser (although you may have to mess with it if it keeps redirecting to gmail's mobile site). I'm sure one of these companies will be bought out by google or apple soon.